# Frequent freezes on 15.04 with kernel 3.19.0-29+

Tags: 15.04, freeze

as already pointed out at

[Frequent freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673767/frequent-freezes)

, I am experiencing systematic freezes since my kernel was automatically upgraded to 3.19.0-29. Same problem happens if I use kernel 3.19.0-30. If I use kernel 3.19.0-28 it does not freeze any more.

Could anyone help me on troubleshooting it please?

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: these issues are classed as bugs.  Please file a bug on launchpad otherwise the developers will not be aware of the issues and thus if released, others will similarly will be affected.

Comment: Thank you. I filed a bug at bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1501281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel 3.19.0-30 is not a supported kernel for Ubuntu 15.04.

The current kernel in stable repository is 3.19.0-28.

You got 3.19.0-30 installed because you had enabled `proposed` repository in System Settings -> Software & Updates. It is a testing kernel.

Remove  testing kernels using Synaptic and disable `proposed`.

But before you remove it I suggest reporting the bug to launchpad. You can do it by running

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

in terminal.

UPDATE: Now kernel 3.19.0-30 is in stable repositories. If it still has issues, report a bug.

Comment: Might be good, but it's false. [3.19.0-30 is in the normal updates and secutiry repository](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12608997/)...

Comment: Now it is there. But it was not when I wrote the answer.

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation. Anyway, the bug is still there (at least in 3.19.0-29), so I filed a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1501281